# Entity Framework select record before and after a date

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my database I have a set of timepoints with a value. The set looks like:

```
public class Point
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RegistrationTime { get; set; }
}
```

Next to this I have a list of date time points. Foreach datetime point I want the two closest timepoints (1 before and 1 after). I can do this with a foreach over my timepoints, but this will result in a lot of queries. Is there any way to execute a query in 1 go with entity framework?

Comment: Is there an index on the `DateTime` column in the database ? How many records are in this table ? A lot of queries is not necessarily bad - one big query in `EF` can end in an out of memory exception.

Comment: In this scenario we need to take 1000 different timepoints, this results in 2000 different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

Point comparePoint = what you have...

```
var pointBefore = db.Points.Where(p=>p.RegistrationTime < comparePoint.RegistrationTime).OrderByDescending(p=>p.RegistrationTime).FirstOrDefault();

var pointAfter = db.Points.Where(p=>p.RegistrationTime > comparePoint.RegistrationTime).OrderBy(p=>p.RegistrationTime).FirstOrDefault();
```